# Is there anything to spell check code that is displayed in the GUI?

Tags: c++, string, qt, user-interface, spell-checking

I am a student programmer using Qt to build several GUI applications for my company and embarrassingly I have a tendency to misspell words from time to time. Obviously it's not really much of an issue for my code as the compiler would be the first to let me know but is there any way to automatically check the spelling of strings or data that is displayed?

I really would like to know if Qt offers anything; boy that would be nice. I didn't see anything in the documentation though. I don't often have this problem but when it does happen it's so embarrassing.

Comment: Make strings translatable and run spellcheck on a Linguist source file.

Comment: interesting, could you elaborate a little more?? will this require me to go through each string in my program? that could be alot of work if so..

Comment: You only have to do this once, and on the pro side you can then localize your application easily if you need to in the future.

Comment: Another quick-and-dirty possibility would be to run the Unix 'strings' utility on your application's executable (e.g. "strings my_app > outfile", or on a Mac:  "strings my_app.app/Contents/MacOS/my_app > outfile").  Then load outfile into a text editor or word processor that has spell-check, and see what is highlighted there.

Comment: interesting; Is an outfile a collections of strings from your code?

Comment: No, `strings` gets the strings from your code, then you use the command line operator `>` to dump that output to a text file which in this case happens to be called `outfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever since I installed VisualAssist, it highlights spelling, even in comments. 
Not sure what it looks like or if it only works with VS...
 I am using it in plain c++.
http://blog.qt.nokia.com/2012/05/22/qt-4-8-2-and-visual-studio-add-in-1-1-11-released/
I hope this helps.